# drop widget beyond the AbsolutePanel gwt dnd

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drop my draggable widgets out of the boundary panel (AbsolutePanel). In my case draggable widgets is an image. And I want to drop it, so that there will be visible only a part of the image, but when I drop it, and some parts of image beyond absolute panel, it drop automatically within absolute panel.
I tried :

dragController.setBehaviorConstrainedToBoundaryPanel(false);

and thought it means that I can drop it where ever I want, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the working solution :)
Here is my code:

```
public class myEntripointClass implement EntryPOint{
    AbsolutePanel droper;
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Panel main = new AbsolutePanel();
        droper = new AbsolutePanel();
        droper.setHeight("300px");
        droper.setWidth("500px");
        main.add(droper);
        content=new AbsolutePanel();
        bt = new Button("Drag and drop it");
        content.add(bt);
        lb = new Label("Label drag and drop");
        content.add(lb);            
        main.add(content);
        manageDnD();
        RootPanel.get().add(main);
    }

    private void manageDnD() {
        PickupDragController dragController = new PickupDragController(
                (AbsolutePanel) content, true);
        dragController.makeDraggable(bt);
        dragController.makeDraggable(lb);
        dragController.addDragHandler(new DragHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onPreviewDragStart(DragStartEvent event)
                    throws VetoDragException {}

            @Override
            public void onPreviewDragEnd(DragEndEvent event) throws VetoDragException {}

            @Override
            public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) { 
            }
            @Override
            public void onDragEnd(DragEndEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DragContext context = event.getContext();
                int x=context.mouseX;
                int y= context.mouseY;
                droper.add(context.selectedWidgets.get(0),x,y);
            }
        });
        NameDropController dropController = new NameDropController(droper);
        dragController.registerDropController(dropController);
        dragController.setBehaviorDragProxy(true);
    }
```

and my DropController class is:

```
public class NameDropController extends AbstractDropController{
    public NameDropController(Widget dropTarget) {
        super(dropTarget);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDrop(DragContext context) {
        int x=getDiff(getDropTarget().getAbsoluteLeft(), context.mouseX);
        int y=getDiff(getDropTarget().getAbsoluteTop(), context.mouseY);
        ((AbsolutePanel)getDropTarget()).add(context.selectedWidgets.get(0),x,y);
        System.out.print("("+context.mouseX+"::,::"+context.mouseY+")");
      }

    @Override
    public void onMove(DragContext context){
    }

    private int getDiff(int val1,int val2){
        return Math.abs(val1-val2);
    }
}
```

Comment: anyway drpping constrained to boundary panel. I found that positioner constraint dropping within boundary panel. How can I avoid it?

Comment: OK, this time I worked it out and adding the sample code with my answer. Please check it out.. may this would help you.

Comment: year... I finnaly did it but with small difference on setting x and y



int x = new WidgetLocation((Image) event.getSource(), boundaryPanel).getLeft()-(context.mouseX-context.desiredDraggableX);
                //the same calculation repeat for top position which equal y axis.
                int y = new WidgetLocation((Image) event.getSource(), boundaryPanel).getTop()-(context.mouseY-context.desiredDraggableY);
                targetPanel.add(context.selectedWidgets.get(0), x, y);

Comment: So you got it solved?
then be my gust to edit the answer with that difference.
And please close the  question by accepting and editing with your 'small difference' in the answer.